# Efficiently merging fields from one array into two other arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let's say you've got three arrays of objects:

```
let a1 = [
  { id: 1, name: 'foo' },
  { id: 2, name: 'bar' },
  { id: 3, name: 'baz' }
]

let a2 = [
  { name: 'foo' },
  { name: 'bar' }
]

let a3 = [
  { name: 'bar' },
  { name: 'baz' }
]
```

The goal is to use `a1` as a source, and add an `id` field to the elements of `a2` and `a3` with corresponding `name` fields in `a1`. What is an efficient way of accomplishing this? *(Note: 'efficient' here meaning 'something more elegant than loops-within-loops-within-loops'.)*

The result should look like this:

```
a2: [
  { id: 1, name: 'foo' },
  { id: 2, name: 'bar' }
]

a3: [
  { id: 2, name: 'bar' },
  { id: 3, name: 'baz' }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) for referencing the id of a given name. Then assign.

```js
var a1 = [{ id: 1, name: 'foo' }, { id: 2, name: 'bar' }, { id: 3, name: 'baz' }], 
    a2 = [{ name: 'foo' }, { name: 'bar' }],
    a3 = [{ name: 'bar' }, { name: 'baz' }],
    map = new Map(a1.map(o => [o.name, o.id]));
    
[a2, a3].forEach(a => a.forEach(o => o.id = map.get(o.name)));

console.log(a2);
console.log(a3);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: These were all good answers, but I like the cleanness of using Map. The overall program this came up in is more complex (Node + MongoDB + filesystem reads/writes), so every bit helps! :)

Answer (score 2):

For an alternative answer, it could be like this.

It doesn't include loops and may be the shortest code in the answers.

```js
const a1 = [{ id: 1, name: 'foo' }, { id: 2, name: 'bar' }, { id: 3, name: 'baz' }];
const a2 = [{ name: 'foo' }, { name: 'bar' }];
const a3 = [{ name: 'bar' }, { name: 'baz' }];

let f = x => a1.filter(a => x.some(y => y.name === a.name));

console.log(f(a2));
console.log(f(a3));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a2.forEach((a2Elem) => a2Elem.id = a1.filter((a1Elem) => a1Elem.name === a2Elem.name)[0].id)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd first take the indexes of the given names, then just map the array to be merged into:

```
function combine(mergeInto, base) {
    let indexes = base.map(e => e.name);
    return mergeInto.map(e => ({
        name: e.name,
        id: base[indexes.indexOf(e.name)].id
    }));
}
```

```js
let a1 = [
    { id: 1, name: 'foo' },
    { id: 2, name: 'bar' },
    { id: 3, name: 'baz' }
]

let a2 = [
    { name: 'foo' },
    { name: 'bar' }
]

let a3 = [
    { name: 'bar' },
    { name: 'baz' }
]

function combine(mergeInto, base) {
    let indexes = base.map(e => e.name);
    return mergeInto.map(e => ({
        name: e.name,
        id: base[indexes.indexOf(e.name)].id
    }));
}

console.log(combine(a3, a1));
```

Answer (score 0):

A single loop proposal - create a `hash table` and then *merge* fields into the arrays - demo below:

```js
let a1=[{id:1,name:'foo'},{id:2,name:'bar'},{id:3,name:'baz'}], a2=[{name:'foo'},{name:'bar'}], a3=[{name:'bar'},{name:'baz'}];

// create a hash table
let hash = a1.reduce(function(p,c){
  p[c.name] = c;
  return p;
},Object.create(null))

// merge the results
function merge(arr) {
  Object.keys(arr).map(function(e){
    arr[e]['id'] = hash[arr[e].name]['id'];
  });
  return arr;
}

console.log(merge(a2), merge(a3));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important;}
```